# Preserve capitalization of column names/keys returned by SYS_REFCURSOR in Oracle

Tags: oracle, cursors

I am using a SYS_REFCURSOR to return JSON data to an ORDS endpoint. I need the case of the returned column names/JSON keys to be preserved for use in my node application. I have tried the following:

```
OPEN l_cursor for SELECT p.productid as "ProductID" from productnew p;

open l_cursor for SELECT p.productid "ProductID" from productnew p;

open l_cursor for SELECT p.ProductID as "ProductID" from productnew p;

open l_cursor for SELECT p.ProductID "ProductID" from productnew p;
```

These all return as `productid` instead of `ProductID`. When I change it to  `as "ProductIDs"`(note the s), I get `productids`, so it is just the capitalization of the key/columnname that is the issue.

Is this possible to change?

Comment: What means "returns productid"? What are you actually doing with the return values?

Comment: @miracle173 I am using the cursor as an `OUT` parameter for an ORDS call in order to use the data in my web application.

Comment: Sorry, but I know nothing about ORDS.

Comment: @miracle173 I appreciate your input regardless. Thank you

Comment: Explains the same kind of issue here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080972/ords-oracle-rest-data-services-capitalize-json-keys..this might help you

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

When I did a

```
declare
cursor_number number;
description_table dbms_sql.desc_tab;
l_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
column_count number;
begin
OPEN l_cursor for SELECT dummy as "Dummy" from dual;
cursor_number:=dbms_sql.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(l_cursor);
dbms_sql.describe_columns(cursor_number,column_count,description_table);
for k in 1..column_count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(description_table(k).col_name);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

the ouput is

```
Dummy
```

as expected. So SYS_REFCURSOR behaves correctly.

Also

```
create table productnew (productid  number)
/
declare
cursor_number number;
description_table dbms_sql.desc_tab;
l_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
column_count number;
begin
OPEN l_cursor for SELECT p.productid as "ProductID" from productnew p;
cursor_number:=dbms_sql.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(l_cursor);
dbms_sql.describe_columns(cursor_number,column_count,description_table);
for k in 1..column_count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(description_table(k).col_name);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

returns

```
ProductID
```

So the problem isn't at the database.

Comment: I am also getting the correct capitalization in SQL Developer. When I call the ORDS endpoint via Postman, or from my node app, I am getting all of the JSON keys back as lowercase. I apologize for not being clearer before.